# Jenkins ClassCastException from SVNRevisionState to MercurialTagAction

Tags: svn, jenkins, mercurial

A little background - We've recently migrated a few projects to HG from SVN, but not all.  Upon doing this, we've installed the Mercurial Jenkins plugin and have updated said builds to utilize that instead of SVN.

What could be causing the below issue?  Note that this only seems to happen for one select job, but nothing in the job configuration files would lead me to believe that there are any references to SVN.

```
Apr 25, 2014 9:14:18 AM hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner runPolling
SEVERE: Failed to record SCM polling for hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@375dff59[my-project]
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.scm.SVNRevisionState cannot be cast to hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialTagAction
        at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(MercurialSCM.java:301)
        at hudson.scm.SCM._compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:356)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:373)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.pollWithWorkspace(AbstractProject.java:1605)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1575)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1493)
        at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:462)
        at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:491)
        at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:118)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<maven2-moduleset plugin="maven-plugin@2.1">
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <logRotator class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
    <daysToKeep>10</daysToKeep>
    <numToKeep>10</numToKeep>
    <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
    <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
  </logRotator>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM" plugin="mercurial@1.50">
    <source>http://foo/my-repo</source>
    <modules></modules>
    <revisionType>BRANCH</revisionType>
    <revision>default</revision>
    <clean>false</clean>
    <browser class="hudson.plugins.mercurial.browser.RhodeCode">
      <url>http://foo</url>
    </browser>
    <credentialsId>bar</credentialsId>
    <disableChangeLog>false</disableChangeLog>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <jdk>(Default)</jdk>
  <triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
      <spec># every 5 minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
      H/05 * * * *</spec>
      <ignorePostCommitHooks>false</ignorePostCommitHooks>
    </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <rootModule>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  </rootModule>
  <goals>clean</goals>
  <aggregatorStyleBuild>true</aggregatorStyleBuild>
  <incrementalBuild>false</incrementalBuild>
  <ignoreUpstremChanges>false</ignoreUpstremChanges>
  <archivingDisabled>false</archivingDisabled>
  <resolveDependencies>false</resolveDependencies>
  <processPlugins>false</processPlugins>
  <mavenValidationLevel>-1</mavenValidationLevel>
  <runHeadless>false</runHeadless>
  <disableTriggerDownstreamProjects>false</disableTriggerDownstreamProjects>
  <settings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider"/>
  <globalSettings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider"/>
  <reporters>
    <hudson.maven.reporters.MavenMailer>
      <recipients></recipients>
      <dontNotifyEveryUnstableBuild>false</dontNotifyEveryUnstableBuild>
      <sendToIndividuals>true</sendToIndividuals>
      <perModuleEmail>true</perModuleEmail>
    </hudson.maven.reporters.MavenMailer>
  </reporters>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers>
    <org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.M2ReleaseBuildWrapper plugin="m2release@0.13.0">
      <scmUserEnvVar></scmUserEnvVar>
      <scmPasswordEnvVar></scmPasswordEnvVar>
      <releaseEnvVar>IS_M2RELEASEBUILD</releaseEnvVar>
      <releaseGoals>clean -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform</releaseGoals>
      <dryRunGoals>clean -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare</dryRunGoals>
      <selectCustomScmCommentPrefix>false</selectCustomScmCommentPrefix>
      <selectAppendHudsonUsername>false</selectAppendHudsonUsername>
      <selectScmCredentials>false</selectScmCredentials>
      <numberOfReleaseBuildsToKeep>1</numberOfReleaseBuildsToKeep>
    </org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.M2ReleaseBuildWrapper>
  </buildWrappers>
  <prebuilders/>
  <postbuilders/>
  <runPostStepsIfResult>
    <name>FAILURE</name>
    <ordinal>2</ordinal>
    <color>RED</color>
    <completeBuild>true</completeBuild>
  </runPostStepsIfResult>
</maven2-moduleset>
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug report: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25523

As a workaround, it suggests heading into the advanced settings for **Source Code Management** and checking **Disable Changelog**, which worked for me.

### Screenshot

[image: Jenkins Screenshot]